# Haskell multi function that takes two numbers and returns the product without using multiplication (*) or division (/) signs

Tags: haskell, product, multiplication

Got our first assignment for my Haskell class and it seems a bit too complex for the first week of class.

The question is as follows: Write a Haskell function that takes two natural numbers and returns their product. the function must not use the multiplication (*) or division (/) operators.

The only way I can think of doing it is with this:

```
product :: [Integer] -> Integer
product []     = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

Except there is a * sign in it.

Am I missing something or am i just an idiot?

Comment: 1. This appears on the surface to fail the most obvious reading of the "takes two numbers" requirement. 2. Do you know how multiplication is typically defined in mathematics? If not, perhaps you should look it up to begin with.

Comment: Multiplication can be defined as addition. 5*3 = 5+5+5 - not a very difficult first-week concept if Grade 4s learn this property :)

Comment: @DanielWagner that's not a very helpful comment, regardless if the numbers are in a list or as parameters technically the above function still "takes two numbers"... Beyond that we should probably strive to be less hostile to someone who even admitted it's his first week. A snarky "look it up" does no favors to someone who does not even know where to start

Comment: Yes Martin i understand that but i am asking how implement that in Haskell. I am not familiar with it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
product :: [Integer] -> Integer
product []     = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

This will be a mess. Your function accepts a LIST of integers and returns an integer. It is nowhere near your specifications.
Now for multiplication, it is addition of one operand 2nd operand times, so your teacher has asked you to to use this basic principle to multiply 2 numbers.

Here is the code for it

```
product :: Integer->Integer->Integer
product x 1 = x
product x y = x + product x (y-1)
```

Beware this will only multiply 2 positive integers. You can now edit the given function to incorporate negative values too.

Comment: Negative values shouldn't be necessary, as the assignment specified natural numbers.  Of course it's a useful exercise anyway.

Comment: while I like this answer you maybe should have first given a hint and then add the answer later (so Josh could have a chance to learn something from it) - +1 anyway

Comment: BTW: nowadays 0 is suppost to be a natural number as well ;) ... maybe @joshc can fill in the blanks for that (try `product 1 0` what do you expect, how does this function here behave?)